# C# .NET console application running over network on multiple machines

Tags: c#, .net, console

I want to host my console application on a central machine on the network, so multiple users can use my console application to process files. Should I be putting a copy of it on every machine that will use it, or is this an acceptable way, and just have a reference link to the one application for each machine?

Do you have any guides on how to fully setup and deploy a console application for over the network?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you put the .EXE file, when they double click to run it, it will run on the client's machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not make multiple copies of the same app. Odds are that you'll have to change it eventually and if you have a copy on each machine using it, it means four places where you have to update the code: 1) your main source control/ work directory, 2-4) the machines where the console lives. And what if one of the machines crashes and needs to be replaced? You'll have to make sure the new image it gets has the console app already on it, adding on to your versioning issues.

Just create a network folder and point people to said network folder. Then with every change or update, everyone gets the same exact version. I usually use TFS for that. Every time someone needs to pull down a console app to generate some code/xml/what have you, they can just pull down latest and run it.

Comment: That is what I was worried about, is having to update multiple copies.

Comment: This won't be an issue with multiple people running at the same time, or do you mean they can make a copy for themselves when they need it, and keep on centralized source for version reasons.

Comment: I am a web applications developer, so new to windows applications like console/Desktop apps. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You should not have an issue with people running it at once because your file system will manage that for you. The only problem is if they have to write to the same file at once in which case you have to tell them that this is what's going on or have a mechanism that waits until the file becomes available. See `Thread.Sleep()` method for some ideas.